# Status post. Django

Tags: python, django

I created an application where users can add posts. I would like to add the post status. Post after adding has the status "active." After 30 days, changes the status to "inactive" How can I do it?

Comment: What have you researched, tried, and found to not work?

Comment: Please, be more specific in your query. Would you expect the community to do the work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't have any idea to solve this issue so here is two:

1. write a background worker (like celery) run it every few hours and mark old posts as inactive
2. add a `created_at` field to your db and instead of marking post as inactive rememvber if `created_at` is older than 30 days you can't edit/update that post.

I personally prefer second solution because that doesn't need a bacground worker